# Google Cloud Shell Editor Not Resuming From Last Closed Session

Tags: google-cloud-shell, google-cloud-shell-editor

I have tinkered with settings, preferences and also save workspace before exiting yet I am unable to make Google Cloud Shell Editor (IDE), launch with my last session's files, even if I open the Workspace file I had saved last.
If this works, I can avoid opening last session's (open) files one by one.

Comment: I just visited https://ide.cloud.google.com/ and what I found is that my Cloud Shell Editor opened and all the files I had been last editing opened and were present.  I know this doesn't help with your setup ... but if it works for me, then there is hope at the end of the line.

Comment: Circling back. Works perfectly now.

Answer (score 1):

There are certain limitations and restrictions for using Cloud Shell. Cloud Shell is intended for interactive use only.
**Non-interactive sessions are ended automatically after one hour**.
**Cloud Shell sessions are capped at 12 hours**, **after which sessions are
automatically terminated.**
And hence, it does not resume from the last closed session. You have to start a new session every time. You can explore more from this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/limitations#usage_limits).

Comment: Thanks for your encouraging reply. Hoping to strike a solution, eventually.
The discussions in the below topic seem to suggest Theia may have this problem for some users:
https: //community.theia-ide.org/t/is-there-a-way-to-launch-and-default-open-a-particular-folder-as-a-workspace/513

Answer (score 0):

*Google Cloud Shell Editor* (gGSE) still does not resume sessions from the last one. It's been more then a month now that I have been working on it.
I found a work around: I now call `edit` in `cloudshell` CLI to open batches of files when I begin.
Cumbersome, but continuing with gGSE for *ReactJS* projects while using *AWS Cloud9* (aC9) for *Python*, since aC9 IDE doesn't yet support *ReactJS* intellisense.
But for this issue, **full marks to gGSE for the smooth IDE and terminal experience**.